# Calculating custom HTML tables by feature for AGOL popups

Tags: python, arcgis-online, popup, html, arcade

I am working on a project that has all of the stops in a bus system. Each stop can serve more than one route and I have broken down ridership by route in each of the columns with a total route ridership, route boardings and route alightings. This data was an object that I transferred to a table. So there is a lot of fields that are 0 since that particular stop is not serving that route.

Each of these data fields have a standard field formula.

- total route ridership = 'R_{route}'
- total route boardings = 'R_{route}_BRD'
- total route alightings = 'R_{route}_ALT'

In the table there is a list of routes separated by `', '` and I am using this to build a list in a for loop to create an html table. I have tried a couple of different methods to no avail to produce something that AGOL or Arcade finds acceptable.

**Method 1: Arcade loop for building HTML**

When Arcade outputs html it does not form a table

**Method 2: Python loop for building Arcade**

The first thing that I tried was building a Python script that would automate some arcade HTML and then used the field in a calculated field by just using `return $feature.html`

```
def htmlTable(routes):
list = routes.split(', ')
html = '<table><tbody><tr><th>Route</th><th>Total Ridership</th><th>Avg Board</th><th>Avg Alight</th></tr>'

for route in list:        
    html += '<th>' + route + '</th>"'
    html += '<th>+' + f'$feature.R_{route}' + '+</th>'
    html += '<th>+' + f'$feature.R_{route}_BRD' + '+</th>'
    html += '<th>+' + f'$feature.R_{route}_ALT' + '+</th></tr>'

html += '</tbody></table>'

return html
```

**Method 1: Python loop for building HTML**

When I put this together I am able to get the html formatting, but the popup ignores my attempt to call fields with Arcade.

[image: AGOL failed popup]

```
def htmlTable(routes):
list = routes.split(', ')
html = '<table><tr><th>Route</th><th>Total Ridership</th><th>Avg Board</th><th>Avg Alight</th></tr>'

for route in list:        
    html += '<tr><th>' + route + '</th>'
    html += '<th>{' + f'R_{route}' + '}</th>'
    html += '<th>{' + f'R_{route}_BRD' + '}</th>'
    html += '<th>{' + f'R_{route}_ALT' + '}</th></tr>'

html += '</table>'

return html
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by just using ArcGIS JavaScript API using a generic function. To build out the popup.

```
const ridershipPopup = (feature) => {

  let routes =  feature.graphic.attributes.RouteList;
  let list = routes.split(', ');

  let filterList = [];
  let obj = '';
  for(let i in list){
    if(!filterList.includes(list[i])){
      filterList.push(list[i]);
    }
  }
  for(let i in filterList){
    obj += 'Route: ' + filterList[i] + '<br>' + `Total Ridership: {R_${filterList[i]}}` + '<br>' + `Average Board: {R_${filterList[i]}_BRD}` + '<br>' + `Average Alight: {R_${filterList[i]}_ALT}` + '<br>';
  };
  return obj
};
```

Then I ended up calling the function in FeatureLayer:

```
  const stops = new FeatureLayer({
    url: 'url',
    popupTemplate: {
      title: 'Stop ID: {stop_id}',
      // ! CALCULATE OUT POPUP TEMPLATE
      content: ridershipPopup,
    },
    outFields: ['*'],
  });
```